# Open Source Knowledge Site

Tags: php, sql, information-management

Basically I'm looking for a solution that's a lot like what you'd find for 'documentation' on sites like php.net

There'd be an admin backend and also a user front end that displays the information.

I'm trying to have a site that has a left navigation as such....

- Category

  - Sub
  - Sub
  - Sub
- Category 2

  - Sub
  - Sub
  - Sub
  - Sub

Etc.....

Now in also viewing an individual "sub" it would show 'next' and 'previous' within the category it's in. I know there's like an open source solution for what I'm looking for. I'd like to stick to PHP/SQL if possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Kind Regards,

Randy

Answer (score 2):

I've used [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) which is simpler than other wiki systems. No database need and has a very nice set of plugins for extending. Implies you learn the syntax, but allows for what you're looking for. You can make the "editable" nature of a wiki "private" (only small group of users or you only)

Comment: DokuWiki is perfect for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your software documentation on Github, a good example of that is [LibGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets).